# "0" vs "none" as css attribute value

Tags: css

I usually put `0` as value when i want to remove something in css. For example:

```
border: 0;
background: 0;
```

Is there any difference between `0` and `none`?

Comment: **this is not a duplicate** because the other questions doesn't mention **background: 0**, which **is handled differently** than border: 0. see the answer below for clarification.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When used with composite styles like `border` and `background`, the values will correspond to different properties.

`border: 0` will set `border-width: 0` while `border: none` will set `border-style: none`.

`background: 0` will set `background-position: 0` while `background: none` will set `background-image: none`.

So, there is a difference. In the case of the border, the difference doesn't make any visual difference as both remove the border, but for the background it can make a difference if you also set any other background properties.

Comment: Can you provide a source @Guffa?

Comment: @MarcoScannadinari: Reference for the border style: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border from there you can go to the separate styles to see what values they accept. Using `border: none;` for example can only mean `border-style` because that's the only of the styles that accept a value `none`.

Comment: May I also add `color` to the background properties above? To set `color` to "off" (which I believe is the ambition here) we should use `background-color:transparent`.

Comment: @Parapluie: Yes, that is one way of removing a color. You can also use `background-color: inherit;` or `background-color: initial;` if you want to replace it with a default color.

Comment: How about `outline: 0;` vs `outline: none;`? Can you tell us the difference between these two attributes?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur: The first sets `outline-width: 0;` while the second sets `outline-style: none;`. As both remove the outline, the effect is the same.